# What is the value of $i=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} $

Tags: complex-numbers

$i=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} $
So

$$=[(-1)^3]^{\frac{1}{2}} =(-1)^{\frac{3}{2}} =[(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}]^3 =i^3 =-i $$

If I solve

$$=i =-i =-i =-i =i?  $$

This step its ok?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Exponents don't work the same way on negative bases.  See this post for a similar fallacy: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303412/where-is-the-fallacy-i-1

Comment: Instead of Nilknarf's link I recommend you start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/438/11619). This and related questions have been asked umpteen times here. The umbrella tag [tag:fake-proofs] is IMHO appropriate here :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Property of exponents can not be applied to non-real and negative bases.

$a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$ **if and only if** $a>0$ or $m,n \in \mathbb Z$. At **least** one of these conditions is must.

Comment: @Typhon IMO, question is clear. The OP tried to prove $i=-i$, and thus concluded that $i=0$, and hence is confused that what is the value of $i$.